# hashlib.sha256 returns different results on Linux

Tags: python, hash, hashlib

I am hashing a file including its name from the path component with the code shown below<sup>1</sup>.
I am getting these strange results (hash value simplified for readability):

| Machine | Hash |
| --- | --- |
| Windows 10 - local 1 | abc |
| Windows 10 - local 2 | abc |
| Windows 10 - CI - Machine 1 | abc |
| Windows 10 - CI - Machine 2 | abc |
| Linux RHEL 7 - local | abc |
| Linux RHEL 7 - CI | abc |
| Linux CentOS 7.9 - local | abc |
| Linux CentOS 7.9 - CI | **abc_linux_other** |

The interesting thing is

- it always works on Windows, doesn't matter the machine, the user, the patch level of windows etc.
- on RHEL 7 it works, on my local machine, on the CI machine, and if I ssh in the CI machine and run it locally (as different user), it always works.
- and then there is CentOS, where in CI, I get these strange results.

On all machines, the same Python version, even the same Python installation is used!

I have absolutly no clue, where this behavior comes from and where I to look?

---

<sup>1</sup> Code

```py
import hashlib
from pathlib import Path

MAX_READ = 4096
some_file = Path("abc/abc.txt")

cs = hashlib.sha256()
buffer = some_file.name.encode("utf-8")
cs.update(buffer)
with open(some_file, "rb") as f:
    while buffer:
        buffer = f.read(MAX_READ)
        cs.update(buffer)
```

Comment: That's not your actual code.

Comment: What is `MAX_READ`? Are you sure it's the same value across all systems?

Comment: What does `print(buffer)` look like on a *real, reproducible* example?  The file contents shouldn't vary so it is probably a difference in the filename (Unicode normalization perhaps)?

Comment: You could also simply hash each `buffer` chunk individually and see which one varies on a passing vs. failing system.

Comment: @KellyBundy that is the actual code - logging

Comment: @C.Nivs: I missed the line while removing the logging statements. It's the same on all platforms (`MAX_READ=4096`)

Comment: @MarkTolonen: I will add real results tomorrow. All file names that are passed to the function are ASCII (that was my initial guess also), so that's not the error. Also not the path separator as it's only the file name.

Comment: Where do you actually finalize the hash to obtain its value?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk What do you mean with *finalize*?

Comment: At some point you have to call `cs.digest()` or `cs.hexdigest()`, you don't show that.